# Writing a function in C to scan different number of args based upon initial character

Tags: c, input, string-parsing

Some background to my problem: we have a board filled with blank spaces, and the user can input one of 9 different commands using the first letter of the command, followed by the required number of arguments (if any). For example, user can enter 'q' to quit, 'h' to display help information. Those two examples don't need anything after them, but for commands like "write" or "erase", the user inputs "w startRow endRow startCol endCol" where the latter 4 args are integers.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to account for the fact that there are different numbers of args that I need to read. Here are the functions I have right now (note: these functions are not in main.c, they are in a separate source file, which is why command is a char*):

```
void getUserInput(char** board, const int numRows, const int numCols, char* command) {
  int numArgsRead;
  const int numArgsNeeded = 1;

  do {
    printf("Enter your command: ");
    numArgsRead = scanf("%c", command);

  } while (!isMoveValid(board, numArgsNeeded, numArgsRead, numRows, numCols, *command));

}

bool isMoveValid(char** board, const int numArgsNeeded, const int numArgsRead, int numRows, int numCols, char command) {

  if (!isValidFormat(numArgsRead, numArgsNeeded)) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }

}

bool isValidFormat(const int numArgsRead, const int numArgsNeeded) {
  bool valid = (numArgsRead == numArgsNeeded);
  char c;

  do {
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (!isspace(c)) {
      valid = false;
    }
  } while (c != '\n');
  return valid;
}
```

Note: it may seem redundant right now, but I'm going to add another function isOnBoard to an else if statement in the isMoveValid function.

The issue I'm having right now is that after reading the initial command character, the isValidFormat function scans through all the rest of the args that have been inputted, so I can't scan them again and assign them to variables. However, I need that function there bc it checks if I've hit a newline, and makes sure I don't scanf the newline on the next iteration of entering a command. How can I get around this so that I can read the values that are entered by the user?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about these would be to read the whole line using `fgets` and then parse it accordingly. Suppose you have a command like

```
A 1 2 3 4
```

You get the whole line and check which command it is. Now you will know how many arguments should be there. You tokenize the string using `strtok` and then convert them to integer or whatever format you need it.

Now next question how to pass it. Take two variables, one of them should be the `argCount` denoting the number of inputs to the command and then an array `argVector` which stores that many number of arguments.

Comment: but wouldn't I need to know the length of the input to use fgets?

Comment: @Ismael.: You specify a maximum length, that would hold. For example 200 char long. That will be the size of the `buffer`.(You specify the maximum limit and then parse it)